# AutoLayout does not pin constraints on the initial load but after going to another view controller and coming back the constrains are pinned

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, ios-autolayout

Attached is a screenshot of the initial load and a screenshot of the load after I return to it from another screen. The costraints for the button on the bottom right doesn't seem to be loading initially. It has a constraint on its height, width, bottom to the superview and right to the superview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu3EE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2micr.png

Comment: Are you adding the constraints in code, or in the Storyboard?  If in code, then show the code.

Comment: There's really not enough information here to even hazard a guess. What I'd do is use Xcode super-cool UI debugging tool; Launch your app in the simulator and when the initial view appears (with the incorrect button placement), click the Debug View Hierarchy button in the debugger pane and explore the views. Find out where the button view is (offscreen? hidden? doesn't exist yet?), what its constraints are set to, and then work backwards from there.

Comment: I did as you said and saw the button is underneath the tab bar on the first load, however, the constraints are the same for the button in both the initial and second load. I did further digging around and found out that if I move the existing line self.selectedIndex = 2 from the viewDidLoad to the viewWillAppear method, the views load properly. However, because of the way the app is constructed I cannot do so. What exactly does this mean is happening?